# Docker compose: my server + nginx. Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops, bad-gateway

I'm just starting to learn docker, and now I'm trying to run two containers with docker-compose - my own mini-server and nginx. My task is:
Start the docker container with my mini-server
Start the docker container with nginx which will proxy all requests from port 8080 to port 81 of the first container
Map port 8080 of the second container to port 80 of the local machine

My nginx and docker-compose files:
[nginx.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD6Yb.jpg)
[docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paqJM.jpg)

It builds successfully, but when I run it and try curl localhost:80 and curl localhost/status, it returns Bad Gateway.
[Bad Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezJnr.jpg)

There are some failures in nginx container logs, but I don't know what does it mean and what should I do.
[nginx logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSfWA.jpg)

After reading other topics with similar problems, I tried to add restart: always and some other things like timeouts in ngix.conf etc, but it didn't help.

I'll be very grateful for any help!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] your question to include your [mcve] as plain text, and directly in the question?